# Can I select Content Builder emails when performing a send from Salesforce using Connector?

Tags: marketing-cloud

We have emails built out in Content Builder, are we able to use these emails when sending from the Sales Cloud using the Connector integration.  I cannot recall if this was implemented in a release or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope, not in Cloud Connector v5.496, only Classic Content is available there. Support told me that within build v5.497 it will be available, that build is in Beta but no information on release yet.

I discovered this via Support Case #14709959, where they said:

> Unfortunately, the Content Builder folder for email is not available yet, it is just available in the beta version of the Cloud Connector (v5.497) which is not released at the moment, but will be soon. We don't have a confirmed date about this. Once the package release is available you may see it on AppExchange. However you can find more about the version [here](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/integrated_products__crm_and_web_analytic_solutions/marketing_cloud_connector_v5/connecting_the_clouds/).

Comment: Do you have a reference for this claim?

Comment: Only my Support Case #14709959, where they said:

"Unfortunately, the Content Builder folder for email is not available yet, it is just available in the beta version of the Cloud Connector (v5.497) which is not released at the moment, but will be soon. We don't have a confirmed date about this. Once the package release is available you may see it on AppExchange. However you can find more about the version here." http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/integrated_products__crm_and_web_analytic_solutions/marketing_cloud_connector_v5/connecting_the_clouds/

Comment: You can [edit] your own posts. Welcome to SFSE!